# form POST in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, forms, post, paypal

I am trying to implement a paypal payment in my .aspx page. I have the following html in my page:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="19218">
  <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BusinessEmail").ToString%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<%= "CityBits Gold " & listplans.SelectedItem.ToString & " listing plan for " & trim(txttitle.text)%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<%= HiddenFieldid.Value%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%= listplans.SelectedValue%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ReturnUrl").ToString & "?requestID=" & HiddenFieldid.Value%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CancelUrl").ToString%>">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

In my aspx page, when i click the paypal button, it just refresh the page. When I put the exact same code (with actual values of course) in a plain html file and click the button, it redirect me to paypal as desired. I have tried using actual values for inputs just like in the html page, but it still does not work.

if it matters, I have update panels in my page, but this form is not inside them.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? It might be something stupid, but this is giving me headaches for 2 days now!

Comment: quick hack :Place a close form on start -> `</form><form target="paypal" ....` to close the asp.net form there. Hopefully you do not have other asp.net elemets like buttons, after that form

Comment: @Aristos Actually I am using a masterpage on this page, so i can not close the form at the start like that. And I do have other asp.net elements after that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the way ASP.NET pages work. ASP.NET always assumes only one large form on the page, and begins to perform various tricks when you introduce a second one.

However what you can use in your case is a Button control and its [PostBackUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. It will handle your inner form correctly, gathering all parameters and performing a post:

```
<form target="paypal">
  ...
  <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="PayPalSubmit"
                   PostBackUrl="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
                   ImageUrl="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" />
</form>
```

Comment: I have actually tried this (sorry for not mentioning) but for some reason when it is redirected to paypal, i get this message: At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to miltoschristelene@hotmail.com and try another option.

Comment: @user2916280, that does not sound like an ASP.NET issue. Use fiddler or firebug, inspect the request and then consult the paypal docs to see if the request matches with what PayPal expects

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known issue with ASP.NET forms when trying to post data to PayPal. Here's a really cool solution that I use all the time for E-Commerce Web Forms applications:

http://jerschneid.blogspot.com/2007/03/hide-form-tag-but-leave-content.html

And here are two personal blog posts expanding on Jeremy Schneider's idea of using a custom version of HtmlForm:

http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/03/08/Solution-to-ASPNET-Form-PayPal-Problem.aspx

http://codersbarn.com/post/2008/03/27/Integrate-PayPal-Checkout-Button-with-ASPNET-20.aspx

Stay away from using double form tags, JavaScript and other hacks.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

/// <summary>
/// This is a special form that can _not_ render the actual form tag, but always render the contents
/// </summary>
public class GhostForm : System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm
{
  protected bool _render;

  public bool RenderFormTag
  {
      get { return _render; }
      set { _render = value; }
  }

  public GhostForm()
  {
      //By default, show the form tag
      _render = true;
  }

  protected override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  {
      //Only render the tag when _render is set to true
      if (_render)
          base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
  }

  protected override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
  {
      //Only render the tag when _render is set to true
      if (_render)
          base.RenderEndTag(writer);
  }
}
```