# PayPal auto-generated button returning to Default

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I'm just starting to develop with ASP.NET and the paypal API and one of the first things I've done is auto-generate the HTML for a PayPal buy now button.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" 
target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="//my key">
<input type="image" 
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" 
border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" 
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This constructs a button for me which is great. However upon clicking, instead of going to the `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr` URL as expected. I simply get a page post back to `"/Default"`.

Do I need to set up anything else with the button?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. You can't have two form tags in ASP.NET. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668525/form-post-in-asp-net-page/22674624#22674624

Comment: @IrishChieftain I like the look at what Jeremy is doing in his GhostForm example, however they are referencing what I can assume to be an older version of ASP.NET with a folder called App_Code. Currently in the process of attempting to translate it into "new" ASP.NET. Will update

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference. There is a shorter JS solution - as long as you're okay with a tiny amount of folks turning off JS in their browsers ;-)